Large Foundation Cracks / Sinking Garage Floor

Hi, I’m looking for some advice on what to do about a large crack in the block foundation as well as the cracking/sinking of the garage slab of my home.
For context, this was a new build that I purchased in December 2021. I purchased directly from the builder and received a “1-year Builders Warranty.” During that first year we had numerous issues, some that the builder never fixed and some that they did.
Since then, we have observed that the garage floor appeared to be settling a bit. This was first observed when I noticed that the garage door no longer sat flush with the slab. Upon further inspection it appears that the “settling” was much worse than anticipated. The garage “slab” is more like 4 independent slabs with large gaps (approx .5”) between them. In some areas that gap has grown larger and no area of the floor is level at this point. I wasn’t aware of the true severity of this until yesterday when we discovered a huge crack in the concrete block foundation that sits beneath the back wall of our garage. It is so severe that you can see light coming in from the garage. The crack is vertical and runs down joint lines as well as straight through the middle of some of the blocks.
Home is in foothills region of NC, we were not impacted by Hurricane Helene. I’ve posted photos above of the damage. Block pic is from yesterday and the garage floor pic is from earlier this year around Spring.
I do not know where to begin here. Please help!


Pictures? Edit and use the mountains/moon icon to post.

You probably want a structural engineer to check it and maybe find the reason.  General location might help plus recent weather.  A lawyer might be in your future depending what the engineer says.

the structure of this site is not like a forum. Move your photos into the question and do not use answers as a way to continue a conversation

Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Have a structural engineer take a look at this.  Your insurance may help with it as well.  Even though you are past the warranty period if you have verified proof the issues started before the warranty was up you may still have a claim.
I cannot tell from pics what is up with the floor, but the block wall shows a problem that should be addressed ASAP.  This may be a sinkhole or just drastic settling from poorly compacted soil. Either way this need professional assessment.
